# Proving that the vector field X is tangent to hypersurfaces.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Consider the map $f: \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R$ ,where
$f=x_1 x_2 x_4 x_6+x_1 x_3 x_5 x_6-x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6$

The normal vector field is
$$N=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_5},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_6})$$
Consequently, the vector field
$$X=(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},0,0,0,0)$$

How would I go about proving that the vector field X is  tangent to hypersurfaces.

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 2):

When you say "the normal vector field," you mean the vector field normal to the level hypersurfaces $\{f=\text{constant}\}$ (wherever the normal is nonzero). What does "normal" mean? It means that this vector at point $p$ is orthogonal to the $\Bbb R^5$ that is the tangent space to the level hypersurface at $p$. Your vector field $X$ is orthogonal to $N$, which means it is tangent to the appropriate level hypersurface.